# Is there any way to change the index of the dataframe for ploting?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, indexing

I am trying to plot my project's data. The plot data is represented as the Index [0,1,2,3,4]. But I want to plot the data as index [3,0,1,4,5].

```
xx = df_new.groupby('Data' ,as_index=False).count().index

values = df_new.groupby('Data').size().values

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

plt.bar(xx ,values)
```

here is my data plot graph:

[image]

Is there any way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try reindex. Say I have the following df

```
     A
0   10.0
1   NaN
2   20.0
3   30.0
4   40.0
5   50.0
6   60.0
7   NaN
```

I can plot

```
df.fillna(0).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

I can also rearrange as follows

```
df.reindex([7,6,4,2,1,3,0,5]).fillna(0).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]